# Line's number of Exception in Python

Tags: python

```
import sys
import linecache

# copied from somewhere
def PrintException():
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    f = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print 'EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj)

def m1():
    # some code

try:
    try:
        m1()
    except:
        PrintException()
except:
    PrintException()
```

It writes the Exception line's number of `m1()`-called line, but I need to know the Exception line's number exactly in function `m1`. Could you please say how to know it?

Comment: what is the purpose of nested `try-except`?

Comment: do you mean - it gives you the no of line from where `m1()` is called and you want the no of line where exactly the exception is (in this case in m1() method definition?).

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov In so I tried to print line's number Exception nested in m1

Comment: @Ankush Rathi Yes

Comment: @AzatIbrakov If you fail once, `try`, `try` again.

Answer (score 1):

To get the exception you have to loop through `.tb_next`

```
import requests, re, time, json, urllib2
import math, os, time
from datetime import datetime

import sys
import linecache

# copied from somewhere
def PrintException():
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    f = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    if tb.tb_next:
        tb_next = tb.tb_next
        while tb_next: # loop until the value is 'None'
          lineno = tb_next.tb_lineno
          tb_next = tb_next.tb_next
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print 'EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj)

def m1():
    # some code
    raise ValueError('Value error')

try:
    try:
        m1()
    except:
        PrintException()
except:
    PrintException()
```

it will output `line 25` not `29` or line not with `m1()`

```
EXCEPTION IN (main.py, LINE 25 "raise ValueError('Value error')"): Value error
```